# Importing D7 DPR in Delphi 2009: "Invalid character in text content"

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2009

I'm trying to open old projects generated in Delphi 7 with Delphi 2009. On some projects, this causes the following error message from the IDE:

"An invalid character was found in text content"

The affected projects are working fine in the old IDE. How can I solve this?

Comment: Where is the error message displayed? Could you post a delphi screenshot?

Comment: There you go: http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/9494/invalidcharacter.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could track down the problem. Although the project files had already been Unicode-encoded, there were some special characters in the .cfg file that caused the hiccups. They were the value of a special file attribute that wasn't visible in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have non-compatible 8-bit character in your .dpr file. Maybe it helps if you either clean the file or convert it to utf-8 with some text editor and try again.

Comment: What are non-compatible 8-bit characters? Does Delphi 7 write those? Anyway, aren't there unicode code points for every bit combination in the first byte due to unicode's downward compatibility?

When I open and convert the dpr as text files with Notepad++, Delphi 2009 agrees to open them. Although, doing the same using a small application written in 2009 with the TStringList.SaveToFile(string, TEncoding) method seems to fail. Doing this using some of the standard TEncoding's (e.g. TEncoding.UTF8, TEncoding.Unicode), the same error message still occurs.